# Ошибка при попытке создания статического метода класса

Tags: javascript

Есть клас:

```
class Student {
    constructor(fullName, direction) {
        this._fullName = fullName;
        this._direction = direction;
    }

    showFullName() {
        let result = this._fullName;
        return result;
    }

    nameIncludes(data) {
        if (this.showFullName().includes(data)) return true;
        return false;
    }

    static studentBuilder(fullName, direction){
        let result = {
            _fullName: fullName,
            _direction: direction 
        };
        return result;
    }
}

const stud1 = new Student("Ivan Petrenko", "web");
const stud2 = new Student("Sergiy Koval", "python");
const stud3 = Student.studentBuilder("Ihor Kohut", "qc");
```

При вызове метода `nameIncludes()` для экземпляров stud1 и stud2 все отработывает отлично, но при попытке вызова метода для экземпляра stud3 все идёт не по плану. Я полагаю, что это из-за того, что это статический метод, но почему это так работает я не знаю, так же, как не знаю, как это исправить.

[image: Error]

Comment: Всё правильно что вы ожидали?

Comment: Я не понимаю, почему если я вызову `console.log(stud1.nameIncludes("Name"));`, то всё работает, а если вызову `console.log(stud3.nameIncludes("Name"))`, то появляется эта ошибка

Comment: потому что stud3 это не Student

Comment: Хмм, а как сделать, чтобы stud3 был Student?

Comment: `static studentBuilder(fullName, direction){
    return new Student(fullName, direction);
}` :D

Comment: Охх, действительно, не додумался, что так можно было. Спасибо!

Comment: Не понятно, в чем смысл такого метода... Результат будет похожим, если перед `return result` добавить `Object.setPrototypeOf(result, Student.prototype);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сатический метод `Student.studentBuilder`

```
const stud3 = Student.studentBuilder("Ihor Kohut", "qc");
```

не возращяет нового `Student`. Только объект

```
    {
        _fullName: fullName,
        _direction: direction 
    };
```

Так что не понятны ваши ожидания по поводу `nameIncludes()`

Как правильно заметил @Алексей Шиманский Вам нужно

```
class Student {
    constructor(fullName, direction) {
        this._fullName = fullName;
        this._direction = direction;
    }

    showFullName() {
        let result = this._fullName;
        return result;
    }

    nameIncludes(data) {
        if (this.showFullName().includes(data)) return true;
        return false;
    }

    static studentBuilder(fullName, direction){
        return new Student(fullName,direction);
    }
}
```